# Getting a count of list elements

Tags: python, list, counting

I have many lists saved in one big list, say `A`.

```
A=[[1,2], [2,1], [3,1], [1,2]]
```

How can I sort this list and get the count of each element in it?

Edit: The only approach i could think of was to fetch each element in the list, further read individual elements in the list obtained by selecting elements of the bigger list.

Comment: Do you mean `A = [[1,2], [2,1], [3,1], [1,2]]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

A = [[1,2], [2,1], [3,1], [1,2]]
print Counter(tuple(i) for i in A)

>>> 
Counter({(1, 2): 2, (3, 1): 1, (2, 1): 1})
```

Comment: Note as your generator expression is the only argument, you can forego the brackets around it and just have `Counter(tuple(i) for i in A)`.